# Can we upgrade from Jhipster 8.0.1 beta version to new stable version available in future?

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-blueprint

Can we upgrade from Jhipster 8.0.1 beta version to new stable version available in future?

I installed Jhipster 8.0.1 beta version and wanted to upgrade to new stable version available in future.
Can anyone help here ?
Jhipster upgradation.

Comment: In theory, you should be able to run `jhipster upgrade`. You might want to try it now that v8 beta 2 is out.